# How to cp / mv or command to a filename set in a variable containing particular character in shellscript?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, args

I run my script via console:

`sh ./application.sh CurriculumVitae\ \(January\ 2020\).pdf`

containing backslashes to allow special characters escaping.

In the *application.sh* I need to make a copy of this input file so I run the following code to actually add those backslashes and copy it:

```
ORIGINAL_FILE="$1"
COMMAND_FILE=$( echo "$ORIGINAL_FILE" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' )

eval cp "$COMMAND_FILE" ".temp/"
```

where $1 is `CurriculumVitae (January 2020).pdf` and $ORIGINAL_FILE is `CurriculumVitae\ \(January\ 2020\).pdf`.

But my `eval cp "$COMMAND_FILE" ".temp/"` fails with the following error:

```
./application.sh: eval: line 52: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./application.sh: eval: line 52: `cp CurriculumVitae\ \(January\ 2020\).pdf .temp/'
```

How can I solve this within the variable? Thanks

Comment: Just enclose the argument in quotes. `'CurriculumVitae  (January 2020).pdf'` and you don't need the escapes and  `sed` nor the  `eval`

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Just `cp "$1" ".temp/"`

Comment: Maybe @KamilCuk you can write it as an answer, otherwise I will do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three lines commands should be replaced simply with this one `cp "$1" ".temp/"`